# Plotting of a Panel dataset in R studio

Tags: r, plot, panel, panel-data

I have a dataset of crime rates in neighborhoods(51) across 5 years (255 observations).
The data is in an xlsx file, I attach an image of the structure of the file.
[image: Data Structure]

I am not experienced working with panel datasets and I am trying to create a plot that shows each neighborhood crime rates over the years (on the same plot).

It should look like 51 lines where the x is the year and the y is the crime rate. There should be some way to identify each neighborhood.

If it is too much to fit in one graph I can also divide it to a number of graphs.

What is the best way to load the dataset to r and then create the plot?

Thank you!

I have tried loading the data with plm package and plotting with scatterplot using foreign package.

Comment: Hi Jov. There are lots of different ways to import data into R, but they are dependent on the file format of your data. Your haven't told us that, so we can't really help you import it. How you plot it is also entirely dependent on the structure of your data set, and we don't have that either. It's not really clear what kind of answer you are expecting given the information you have included in your question. Could you perhaps edit your question to include this information? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron , you are totally right, I edited the question and added the info, thank you!

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg